# different forms of uploading data

Tags: php, mysql

i would like to know if their is a different way of uploading data to a database im using insert into but its not working every time i try to upload something it creates a different row with email is their a way to uploading lots of data in the same row or even combining the data into one row. im creating shirts and the user is going to be able to upload new images for the shirt and giving them a name each time the user creates a shirt i want it to be unlimited shirts

```html
$email=$_POST['email']; 



 
 $sql = "SELECT * from register_login WHERE  email='$email'";
 $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
 if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
  echo "<p>Invalid email Address</p>";
 } else {
   require_once("configur.php");


 
$query='INSERT INTO shirt_table SET email="'.$_POST[email].'", title="'.$_POST[title].'", keywords="'.$_POST[keywords].'"';

if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$mysqli->close();
    }
```

Comment: Use UPDATE instead of INSERT? INSERT is ment to create a new row. UPDATE is ment to edit an existing one.

Comment: i used update but i can only post one row i want to be able to upload at least 10 different images with title and keywords

Comment: Then count the number of uploaded files. Create a for loop and insert each one after another. Although what I really think you need to do is to normalize your database: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: thank you i will fix my mistake